# Reactjs render geometry with Latex

Tags: reactjs

Anybody please help me
how to render this code to geometry with Latex in reactjs

```
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,5){A'}
  \tkzDefPoint(6,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(2,-2){C}
  \tkzDefPointsBy[translation= 
    from A to A'](B,C){}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
  \tkzDrawPoints(A',B',C')
  \tkzLabelPoints[left](A,A')
  \tkzLabelPoints[right](B,B')
  \tkzLabelPoints[below right](C')
  \tkzLabelPoints[below](C)
 \tkzDrawSegments[style=dashed].  (A,B A',B)
  \tkzDrawSegments(A,C C,B A',B' 
B',C' C',A' A,A' B,B' C,C' 
 A',C)
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
   } 
  \end{ex}
```

Thanks so much